# Is it necessary to check an optional argument before passing it to another optional argument?

Tags: fortran, optional-arguments

I have the following question concerning the usage of optional argument. Let's say I have the following routine `aaa` defined in module `m_aaa`

```
MODULE m_aaa
SUBROUTINE aaa(a, b)
  INTEGER           :: a
  INTEGER, OPTIONAL :: b
END SUBROUTINE
END MODULE
```

now I have a second routine that uses the module `m_aaa`. Is it possible to pass the optional argument like this

```
! Variant 1:
SUBROUTINE bbb(c, d)
  USE m_aaa 
  INTEGER           :: c
  INTEGER, OPTIONAL :: d
  CALL aaa(c,d)
END SUBROUTINE
```

or is it necessary to check the presence of the optional argument d like this:

```
! Variant 2:
SUBROUTINE bbb(c, d)
  USE m_aaa 
  INTEGER           :: c
  INTEGER, OPTIONAL :: d
  IF (PRESENT(d)) THEN
    CALL aaa(c,d)
  ELSE
    CALL aaa(c)
  ENDIF
END SUBROUTINE
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not necessary to check to presence of an optional dummy argument before passing it as an actual argument to another optional dummy argument.

This is allowed by 12.5.2.12 paragraph 4 (ISO/IEC 1539-1 (Draft 7 June 2010) aka Fortran 2008) regarding optional actual arguments that are not present:

> Except as noted in the list above, it may be supplied as an actual argument corresponding to an optional dummy
>   argument, which is then also considered not to be present.